# How do I scrape the text that appears when I hover over the element?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, scrapy

So on the e-commerce webpage (https://www.jooraccess.com/r/products?token=feba69103f6c9789270a1412954cf250) the color name of the product is displayed when I hover over it, I was able to determine what the new line in HTML code that appears when I hover over, but I don't know how to grab the text ('NAVY').

```
<div class="ui top left popup transition visible Tooltip_Tooltip__M0LJL Tooltip_black__heZoQ" style="position: absolute; inset: auto auto -7494px 378px;">NAVY</div>
```

```
driver.get("https://www.jooraccess.com/r/products?token=feba69103f6c9789270a1412954cf250")  
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Swatch_swatch__2X1CY']")))   
for el in elements:       
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).perform()   
    mouseover = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui top left popup transition visible Tooltip_Tooltip__M0LJL Tooltip_black__heZoQ'")))      
    print(mouseover)
```

Comment: Share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Please see below

`driver.get("https://www.jooraccess.com/r/products?token=feba69103f6c9789270a1412954cf250")

elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Swatch_swatch__2X1CY']")))


for el in elements:

   
 ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).perform()
  mouseover = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui top left popup transition visible Tooltip_Tooltip__M0LJL Tooltip_black__heZoQ'")))
    
print(mouseover)`

Comment: You want get all those color values?

Comment: This element is using multiple classes so it can't be grabbed by selenium so it'll be better if you look for a parent element with unique attributes and this go go down the ladder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came to before I saw the answers here:

```
 elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Swatch_swatch__2X1CY']")))
    for el in elements:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).perform()
        page = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')
        print(page.find("div", class_="ui top left popup transition visible Tooltip_Tooltip__M0LJL Tooltip_black__heZoQ").text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code.Your `xpath` expression seems wrong for tool tip element.
I have changed that and also to get the text value you need to `print(element.text)`

```
driver.get("https://www.jooraccess.com/r/products?token=feba69103f6c9789270a1412954cf250")  
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Swatch_swatch__2X1CY']")))   
for el in elements:       
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).perform()   
    mouseover = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ui top left popup transition visible Tooltip_Tooltip__M0LJL Tooltip_black__heZoQ']")))      
    print(mouseover.text)
```

Output on my terminal.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Good one, but I've already found the way (see my solution below)

Answer (score 0):

for some reason I couldn't get your site to work with the platform I am using but I managed to create an example. I would recommend using the Actions library and use it to move to the element in question.

`ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='dropdown-toggle']")).perform()`

This is for the site I am using but if you change the xpath for your own element it should work. Once the driver has done this you can find the element you want that is revealed by hovering. You should be able to just put this in a for loop and you are good to go.

I made a runnable example [here](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/f59bee4c-3a3e-4cd1-9af3-3ca5c169ab87?projectId=bugtestproject2)